# Error when changing text in textbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a simple UI, just a few textboxes and a couple of buttons.  The concept is basically that of a voting app for a spreadsheet I maintain.  As the script runs it will present each row of the spreadsheet into the textboxes and allow the user to vote on that item.  I created the UI by hand:

```
function BuildUI() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Voting Machine").setWidth(700);
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var buttonWidth = "125px";

// Panels
var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
var horzPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
var buttonGrid = app.createGrid(1,3);

// Textboxes
var txtCat = app.createTextBox().setName("txtCat").setId("txtCat");
var txtIdea = app.createTextBox().setName("txtIdea").setId("txtIdea");

// Handlers
var handler = app.createServerHandler();
handler.setCallbackFunction("recordVote");
handler.addCallbackElement(txtCat).addCallbackElement(txtIdea);

// Buttons
var voteNo = app.createButton("No").setId("voteNo")
  .addClickHandler(handler).setWidth(buttonWidth);
var voteMaybe = app.createButton("Maybe").setId("voteMaybe")
  .addClickHandler(handler).setWidth(buttonWidth);
var voteYes = app.createButton("Yes").setId("voteYes")
  .addClickHandler(handler).setWidth(buttonWidth);

horzPanel.add(txtCat).add(txtIdea)
buttonGrid.setWidget(0, 0, voteNo)
  .setWidget(0, 1, voteMaybe)
  .setWidget(0, 2, voteYes);
mainPanel.add(horzPanel).add(buttonGrid);

app.add(mainPanel);
doc.add(app);
}
```

The issue is that when I call my NextIdea function I get an error:

```
function NextIdea() {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
... Get the next row of the spreadsheet ...
app.getElementById("txtCat").setText("TestValue"); // <--- This is the error line
```

On the line where I attempt to set the text in the text box I receive an error "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed."  In the debug window it gives me an object number, but there are no properties and trying `.getText` returns as undefined.

Both of these are fired by my ProcessVotes function, which is called by a custom menu item in the spreadsheet:

```
function ProcessVotes() {
BuildUI();
NextIdea();
}
```

This is my first attempt at creating a GAS, not sure what I'm missing.  I do see a lot of examples using `return app;` at the end of a function, but I am under the impression that is only for use when the script is published as a service.  I'm trying to use this inside a spreadsheet (using `onOpen` instead of `onGet`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this part :

```
function NextIdea() {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
... Get the next row of the spreadsheet ...
app.getElementById("txtCat").setText(nextRowCat) // <--- This is the error line
```

What is nextRowCat ? is it supposed to be a string (then you forgot the '') ? is it a variable with a a string value ?

Anyway, it should be a string ;-)

EDIT following your comment : did you try your code with this new version exactly (`.setText("TestValue")`)?

Also I don't see any show(app) in your main function (the one where you create your UI instance app)... I guess it would be easier to help if you show the whole code or at least a simplified but 'runnable' code where you get the error.

Concerning `getText()` that returns undefined, this is a normal behavior : there is no such method on textBox...([see docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textbox)) The usual way to retrieve its value is by using `e.parameter.textBoxName` in a handler function.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that when I cut out the processing for the next row you can't see where that variable is being defined.  I'll edit the question to make that clearer.  However, it is a variable that is assigned (and I can verify it has the value it should have in the debug view)

Comment: The issue was I was attempting to use `.setText = "TestValue"` in my live code, where as, when I created the example here (I made it mostly up trying to get the code short) I used `.setText("TestValue")`, which works, as expected.